# genfromtext() numpy function for reading weight csv files doesn't work in Jupyter (Face Recognition DL assignment )

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, deep-learning, jupyter

I downloaded the DL Face Recognition code (Andrew Ng course) and tried to run it on my own machine. But `fr_utils` file for loading weights for Facenet throwing constant error while opening the csv file.

**Code:**

```py
for name in WEIGHTS:
    if 'conv' in name:
        conv_w = genfromtxt(paths[name + '_w'], delimiter=',', dtype=None) # error occurs here
        conv_w = np.reshape(conv_w, conv_shape[name])
        conv_w = np.transpose(conv_w, (2, 3, 1, 0))
```

**Error:**

> ./weights/conv1_w.csv not found.

Any help or suggestion would be great. Thanks!!

Comment: Either file name is wrong or the directory is wrong.  It's not a `genfromtxt` problem, it's a file OS error.

Comment: Thanks! The file is there in weights folder of current directory, all names cross verified again. And it says - './weights/conv1_w.csv' file not found. So, it is reading the path correctly but cant read the file which is there.

Comment: Argue with your OS, not me!

Comment: You're probably working (I mean Jupyter) in another directory. Check it: `import os; os.getcwd()`

Comment: Thanks everyone.
it worked. there were shortcuts of files rather than files itself. My bad!!